# Groovy to validate the list of node values with the values stored in a property step

Tags: groovy, soapui

[Properties Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEYRw.jpg)Response Snippet

```
    <tns:TAResponse
    xmlns:tns="http://webconnectivity.co.uk/">
    <tns:SessionToken>84hjfutryh47849dkdhg9493493=</tns:SessionToken>
    <tns:PartyId>1234</tns:PartyId>
    <tns:ResponseType></tns:ResponseType>
    <tns:MessageUUId>12341F17-ABC9-3E99-1D12-B8289POO2107</tns:MessageUUId>
    <tns:Matches>
        <tns:IntegrationServiceMatch>
            <tns:InternalReference>2066856</tns:InternalReference>
            <tns:ErrorsAndWarnings>
                <tns:IntegrationServiceErrorCode>
                    <tns:ErrorCode>W000026</tns:ErrorCode>
                    <tns:Description>Settlement Date not within tolerance</tns:Description>
                </tns:IntegrationServiceErrorCode>
                <tns:IntegrationServiceErrorCode>
                    <tns:ErrorCode>E000033</tns:ErrorCode>
                    <tns:Description>Number on message does not match</tns:Description>
                </tns:IntegrationServiceErrorCode>
                <tns:IntegrationServiceErrorCode>
                    <tns:ErrorCode>E000001</tns:ErrorCode>
                    <tns:Description>NO likely matches</tns:Description>
                </tns:IntegrationServiceErrorCode>
            </tns:ErrorsAndWarnings>
        </tns:IntegrationServiceMatch>
    </tns:Matches>
</tns:TAResponse>
```

I have stored all these Errorcode and Description in a property step. I need to validate whether these Errorcode and Description in the response matches with the property step. (sequence is not a deal)
Can someone pls guide me through groovy? 
Previously i had to validate only one errorcode and desc from the response. so i validated using below script.

```
def content = new XmlSlurper().parse(file)
def respType = content.Body.TAResponse.ResponseType.text()
def errAndWarn = content.Body.TAResponse.Matches.IntegrationServiceMatch
assert errAndWarn.size() == 1
for (def i=0;i<errAndWarn.size();i++)
{
    assert errAndWarn[i].ErrorsAndWarnings.IntegrationServiceErrorCode.ErrorCode == "E000033"
    assert errAndWarn[i].ErrorsAndWarnings.IntegrationServiceErrorCode.Description == "Number on message does not match"
}
```

Comment: Can you post all the xml, not just an invalid snippet from it?

Comment: Do you need to check all the properties to be found in the response? or a few?

Comment: @Rao I need to check all the properties. Because that is my expected validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below `Script Assertion` for the SOAP Request test step itself, that will avoid additional `Groovy Script` test step.

This assumes that the name of the **Properties test step name** is `Properties`. If its name differs, then change in the script accordingly.
**Script Assertion**

```
//Change the name of the Properties test step below
def step = context.testCase.testSteps['Properties']

//check if the response is not empy
assert context.response, 'Response is empty or null'

//Parse the xml
def parsedXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response)

//Get the all the error details from the response as map
def errorDetails = parsedXml.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'IntegrationServiceErrorCode'}.inject([:]){map, entry ->    map[entry.ErrorCode.text()] = entry.Description.text(); map    }
log.info "Error details from response  : ${errorDetails}"

//loop thru xml error codes and verify against the properties of Properties Test Step
errorDetails.each { key, value ->
    assert step.properties[key]?.value == value, "Unable to match value of the property ${key} "
}
```

EDIT: based on OP's comment

**Groovy Script** test step:

```
//Change the name of the Properties test step below
def step = context.testCase.testSteps['Properties']

//Parse the xml like you have in your script
def parsedXml = new XmlSlurper().parse(file)

//Get the all the error details from the response as map
def errorDetails = parsedXml.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'IntegrationServiceErrorCode'}.inject([:]){map, entry ->    map[entry.ErrorCode.text()] = entry.Description.text(); map    }
log.info "Error details from response  : ${errorDetails}"

//loop thru xml error codes and verify against the properties of Properties Test Step
errorDetails.each { key, value ->
    assert step.properties[key]?.value == value, "Unable to match value of the property ${key} "
}
```

**EDIT2:** Based on additional requirement, adding below **Groovy Script**

```
//Change the name of the Properties test step below
def step = context.testCase.testSteps['Properties']

//Parse the xml like you have in your script
def parsedXml = new XmlSlurper().parse(file)

//Get the all the error details from the response as map
def errorDetails = parsedXml.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'IntegrationServiceErrorCode'}.inject([:]){map, entry ->    map[entry.ErrorCode.text()] = entry.Description.text(); map    }
log.info "Error details from response  : ${errorDetails}"

def failureMessage = new StringBuffer()

//Loop thru properties of Property step and check against the response
step.properties.keySet().each { key ->
   if (errorDetails.containsKey(key)) {
       step.properties[key]?.value == errorDetails[key] ?:  failureMessage.append("Response error code discription mismatch. expected [${step.properties[key]?.value}] vs actual [${errorDetails[key]}]")
   } else {
       failureMessage.append("Response does not have error code ${key}")
   }
}
if (failureMessage.toString()) {
  throw new Error(failureMessage.toString())
}
```

Comment: Well, remove `assert context.response` line and change `def parsedXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response)` to `def parsedXml = new XmlSlurper().parse(file)`. You should be good.

Comment: You should still be able to validate in Script Assertion as well. Any ways, edited the answer. Please take a look.

Comment: This works perfect:) Can you make it possible the below statement. This would narrow down my validation. "I have these expected 3 errorcode and description in my property step. If the response have few more errorcode and description (say 4 including these 3), then the groovy should not fail. Just want to validate whether my expected 3 are present in response. Whereas, if vice versa (only 2 in the response but in expected i have 3) then groovy should fail at this point".

Comment: May be you can show the screen shot of properties step. What I am not clear is do you need to have all the properties in Property test step needs to be present in the response? The above solution asserts that what ever present in response are valid by looking up in the Properties step.

Comment: Please check the screenshot attached in question. (Properties Screenshot near Response Snippet). Here i just have 2 Error code and Description. I need to validate that these expected Error code and Description should be present in the response. It can be 5 or 6 or 7 errcode and desc in the response. not bothering about the rest. all i need to validate whether my expected errorcodes are present in the response. Please let me know if this is not clear.

Comment: Wow Rao:):) This is perfect which i want..:) Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Thank you for patiently explaining and trying it out. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do:

```
content.Body
       .TAResponse
       .Matches
       .IntegrationServiceMatch
       .ErrorsAndWarnings
       .IntegrationServiceErrorCode.each { node ->
    println "Error code is ${node.ErrorCode.text()} and Description is ${node.Description.text()}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur response @tim_yates