# Groovy Assertion to append the response tagvalues and set in the properties

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have the below response which i got from JDBC test step. This includes ErrorCode, ErrorType & ErrorText.

```
<Row rowNumber="1">
     <ErrorType>W</ErrorType>
     <ErrorCode>000001</ErrorCode>
     <ErrorText>Message receiver not set to insurer or reinsurer</ErrorText>
  </Row>
  <Row rowNumber="2">
     <ErrorType>W</ErrorType>
     <ErrorCode>000002</ErrorCode>
     <ErrorText>Service Provider is not present in the message</ErrorText>
  </Row>
```

I would like to append the ErrorType & ErrorCode to set in 'Name' column and ErrorText in the 'Value' column of the Properties test step which i've created next to JDBC test step. 
My Properties step should be like in the below Screenshot.

[image]

Believe this can be done by adding Groovy Assertion in the JDBC test step. Can someone please help with this? Please let me know for more information

Comment: Harry, how are you going to use these values later? That would help to formulate better approach. What if you get more `Row`s of data?

Comment: I'm selecting few rows only (max 5-6 which is the expected result for validation) in that JDBC test step.. so no worries of large chunk rows.. after saving in the Properties step i do have different testing ..

Comment: Ok, what do you need to do once you store them into properties which is the main question?

Comment: after storing in the Properties step i have different kind of validation.. which you have already solved in the below thread..:) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42954078/groovy-to-validate-the-list-of-node-values-with-the-values-stored-in-a-property.. before this i've added manually in the Properties.. now i have to pull data from DB and store it in the Properties.. that's why

Comment: Thank you Harry for clarifying. Please check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Script Assertion for the JDBC Request test step. No additional Groovy Script test step is required.

**Script Assertion**

```
//Define the property test step name, change if needed
def stepName = 'Properties'
//check the response
assert context.response, 'response is empty'
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response)
//Get the response data as map
def map = xml.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'Row' }.inject([:]){m, item -> m[item.ErrorType.text()+item.ErrorCode.text()] = item.ErrorText.text();m}

def step = context.testCase.testSteps[stepName]
//Use below statement if you need to remove existing properties and just keep the properties from current response only
step.propertyNames.each { step.removeProperty(it)}
//Create properties as needed into properties step from jdbc response
map.each { step.setPropertyValue(it.key,it.value)}
```

You check online for getting the jdbc response as map - <kbd>[Demo](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5162901534932992)</kbd>

Comment: Note that the answer is edited to handle removing existing properties from previous runs. Now it always keep the properties which are part of current jdbc response only.

Comment: Thanks Rao.. this worked.. but while using the code <!-- language: java --> assert context.response, 'response is empty' , i'm getting the error message "response is empty" So, I've just tweaked the code <!-- language: java --> def resp = context.testCase.getTestStepByName("JDBC Stepname").getPropertyValue("ResponseAsXml").

Comment: @Harry, not sure how you did. But that works when you actually run the test or if you already have the response for the jdbc step. otherwise, you get the null.

Comment: Yes.. i have the response in my step.. just by replacing my code this works.. took the screenshot as well.. but i'm unaware of how to insert the screenshot in comments.. but however i've got the output from you.:) Thanks for your wonderful response as always:)

Comment: @Harry, glad it helped.